# How to set a category flag colour using EWS API in C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get mail items from an exchange folder in Microsoft Outlook using EWS API.

Currently I am able to set the mail Item category using

```
 Item item = Item.Bind(service, findResults.ElementAt(0).Id);
            // Update the category 
            if (!item.Categories.Contains("mymessage"))
            {
                item.Categories.Add("mymessage");
            }
```

I am able to then see the corresponding mail with the category set.

How to add a colour to the mailItem category...like the colour flags available (blue or green)?

Comment: What have you tried? There are a number of references available like so: http://www.infinitec.de/post/2011/07/28/Working-with-the-Master-Category-List%E2%80%93EWS-edition.aspx

Comment: I didn't know how to start... I was looking for extended properties.. but couldn't find anything

Comment: I also saw that Categories was a list of strings.. so that also was a dead end

Comment: Did you read the article I linked?

Comment: This will give me list of category colors available and allow me to add categories fine.. but how to add that to a specific mail item?

Comment: You can't, you set the Category of the Item like you are and Outlook/owa or other mail client then needs to read the master category list and will display the colour based on a matching category in the list. If no match is found then it won't show a color

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of the categories that exist you can use : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e5c5f072-0b5c-49ce-9db7-57f76f5e011e/edit-master-category-list-in-exchange-2010-via-ews?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

The code dosen't compile anymore you should change :

```
 UserConfiguration owaCategories = new UserConfiguration(
        this.service,
        "CategoryList",
        parentFolderId);
```

To :

```
 UserConfiguration owaCategories = UserConfiguration.Bind(
       this.service,
       "CategoryList",
       parentFolderId, 
       UserConfigurationProperties.XmlData);
```

You can then use something like :

```
    var cat = new MasterCategoryList(exchange, userMailbox);
    cat.Load();
    EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id);
    email.Categories.Add(cat.Last().Name);// or anything so you find the category you want
    email.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AutoResolve);
```

If you want to add a category you could add some code modifying :       `owaCategories.XmlData` and using `owaCategories.Update()` in `MasterCategoryList`